# How can I integrate MS-access UI with .Net web environment

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ms-access, c#-to-vb.net

We have a legacy software which was built in MS-Access (UI) but was using Sqlserver 2005 as database server.
The UI in Ms-Access has got Menus with different menu-items.  But some of the menu-items doesn't have screens yet (incomplete).  So we decided now to move to .net environment (i.e. .net web application).  Here is my main question.

Firstly I want start working on the screens in .net (.net web application) which are incomplete for the menu-items in MS-Access.  Secondly I will be completing the other screens which are now working in MS-Access UI.  So how can I use/call .net web application screens when ever user clicks on menu-items in MS-Access UI.

Please suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It not really practical to integrate screens built in Access with some web based forms. I not sure why or who or what was suggested to you that such an approach is EVER used in our industry.

You can most certainly launch any web form or web site or launch any URL form the Access client running on your desktop. The code to launch that URL is:

```
Application.FollowHyperlink "path to web form or site goes here"
```

So you can place a button or menu in an Access form to launch a web form, or even launch eBay if you want. However I do not think the issue (or solution) is the ability to launch some web form, but is having parts of the application talk to each other.

An application becomes useful since all the application parts can tightly talk to each other. Access is a great RAD tool due to great ease as to one form launching a report or another form and passing information. And all of that application can EASY share common code and routines that allows you to accomplish useful business tasks.

So when you click on a detail row in an Access grid of data (continues form), then launching another form to edit the one record takes one line of code. So an application is never really just a single standalone form to edit data, but the talking between the forms and use of code and how those objects dance together is what really makes an application useful. If an application was just forms with no code then I think we would be all out of job in this industry.

The model of how you navigate and build web applications is rather different then how Access works. I mean if you have 5 browsers open, which browser has some form to edit your data and which browser is watching videos on YouTube?

You really cannot approach such a half-baked system in which some forms are in Access and parts of the application are web, based.  The only way this is practical is if the web forms do not need to work with or use any of the code in the client forms.

However, you CAN build web forms in Access 2010. In other words, in the Access client you can build both client forms and web forms. The client forms can call and use web forms (they run in the client) as regular forms and things like where clauses etc. will work). When you publish to the web, then ONLY the web forms run. Here is a video of an access application of mine, and note how at the half way point I run the same forms in a web browser:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

However, the above ability in Access right now cannot work with sql server, and must use SharePoint (or the upcoming office 365).

So no question the concept of moving bits and parts out of an application to being web based makes sense (so your concept of not moving ALL of the applicaton out to the web makes sense). However, the parts being moved out to the web must make sense as web or stand alone and not require integration with the client forms (at least during use).

In other words if you have a legacy payroll system in Access now, but want employees to enter their payroll hours, then that new web part is separate from the payroll system. And no question the payroll system could take and pull hours from the new employee hour entry system that is web based.

However, the idea that menus and parts of the client based application will seamlessly launch and use the web browser parts makes no sense at all . Again this makes zero sense and you are barking up the wrong tree here. As noted, if the web part is really a separate business process, then there are some possibilities here.

Last but not least, you can certainly build a set of web services (application business code and logic that is separate from the UI) on the .net web site. This separate business layer could then be used by both the Access client forms and the web forms. However, once again such a setup likely suggests that you better off to build the application as web based anyway as the web based forms can talk and use the business code with greater ease then the client forms can – only exception here again is if you using Access web services, then both web or client forms can use the stored procedures and business routines you write to run server side.

Last but not least, perhaps your problem(s) are solved by increased connectivity, and not really the need for web based? I address this question in the following article of mine.

http://www.kallal.ca/Toweb/Index.html

Comment: Hi Albert D. Kallal. First of all, I thank for your descriptive answer on this subject. I know it is a bad practice. But because of time constraint we want to move with designing web forms first and use them from MS-Access, while developing full-fledged web application.

Comment: This application is to be used for internal purpose. So the web application will be used as intranet application only.
As I said,  Instead of building new screens and writing code in VBA for access. We want to do the same in implementing firstly creating webforms and lunching them from access.  And these webforms data is updated directly on Sqlserver 2005. After we are done creating the new web forms for those incomplete menus in Access UI.  We are going to start freshly a new web application (utilizing already created webforms) for all the menus which are now working

Comment: Yes actully the web parts which I want to launch from MS-access will not require any integration for now. But after reading your answer on integrating/not to integrate, I am thinking now, using webservices makes sense to me -or- use Access 2010 by building web forms and utilize them in -(our application is actually running on Access 2007) Thank you so much for you long answer to my question and I follow your suggestions, If anything I am stuck I will defiantly take your help 
Once again Thank you so very much!!!!